# JavaScript: How to handle memory in growing arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I've got a rather simple function which fires on every keyup. What it does is marking the input text from TinyMCE on a certain condition (the sentence is long) and then shows the highlighted text in TinyMCE editor.

This works like a charm at first glance. But as the text grows the array the function is taking longer and longer to execute.

Is there a brilliant way to do something along the lines of detecting where the input cursor is in the text, and then only analyze the surrounding words (could be the current sentence for an example) and the reuse the rest of the text?

The code goes like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myTextArea" contenteditable="true">
Just put lorem ipsum here.
</div>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#myTextArea',
  height: 300,
  setup: function(ed) {
    ed.on('change', myCustomInitInstance);
    ed.on('keyup', myCustomInitInstance);
    ed.on('paste', myCustomInitInstance);
    ed.on('cut', myCustomInitInstance);
  },
  init_instance_callback: "myCustomInitInstance",
  });

function myCustomInitInstance(inst) {
  var rawText = tinyMCE.get('myTextArea').getContent({
    format: 'text'
  });


var sentenceArray = rawText.split(".");
  var matchWarning = [];
  var longSentence = 16;
  var words;
  var wordCounter;
  var output;

  for (var i in sentenceArray) {
    words = sentenceArray[i].split(" ");
    wordCounter = words.length;
    if (wordCounter > longSentence) {
      matchWarning.push(sentenceArray[i]);
    }
  }

  var editor = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
  // Store the selection
  var bookmark = editor.selection.getBookmark();

  // Remove previous marks and add new ones
  $(editor.getBody()).unmark().mark(matchWarning, {
    acrossElements: true,
    "separateWordSearch": false,
  });

  // Restore the selection
  editor.selection.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve speed in this are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see one problem with your code. Having a `onchange` and a `onkeyup` function triggers your callback twice every time you write down a single letter.
There are a few things you could try:

- If you are just splitting into sentences, why don't you wait until a "." is written down and then trigger your loop?
- The loop should be faster if you make one with length caching, but this should be more performant if the array is very long. `for (var i = 0, len = sentenceArray.length; i < len; i++)`
- You should use a debounce function. This way you trigger the loop just once in a defined time or every keyup or change. Check this David Walsh's debounce function: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

  ```
  // Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
  // be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
  // N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
  // leading edge, instead of the trailing.
  function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
      var timeout;
      return function() {
          var context = this, args = arguments;
          var later = function() {
              timeout = null;
              if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
          };
          var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
          if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
      };
  };
  ```

This way your loop will not execute if there is already another loop executing, which I think is the thing is draining your performance.

Cheers!

Comment: Nice. Took me a while to get the grasp on how the debouncer works. But now it works like a charm :) Much more fluid.
I don't wanna run only on (. ! ? and so forth) since people often stop typing in the middle of a sentence. And I want to validate the text as quickly as possible :) The debouncer is perfect way to achieve this in an efficient way.

Comment: A little clarificatoin @Jorge 

When I use the debouncer function my Chrome Inspect Tool constantly pauses when I try to inspect. Am I using it the wrong way or is this to be expected?